# How to fix the error "async callback wasnt invoked within 5000ms specified by jest.settimeout() using react testing library?

Tags: react-testing-library

i have a test like below which works most of the times but sometimes throws error "async callback wasnt invoked within 5000ms timeout specified by jest.settimeout()

```
test('can delete', async () => {
    //some logic to render component
    await utils.waitForDomChange();
    click icon
    await utils.waitForDomChange();
    expect(queryAllByTestId('remove')[2]).toBeUndefined();
});
```

I am not sure what is causing this problem. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bu default timeout is set to 5000ms but it can take longer than that to resolve async call. Try setting timeout to 15s by adding this at the top of your script: `jest.setTimeout(15000)`. Note that timeout is set for all tests, so multiple `async/await` tests will need higher timeout.